# Handle Multiple toast notification in Action Center?

Tags: c++, notifications, toast

We are using below link to handle toast notification from win 10 action center.

"https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tiles_and_toasts/2015/10/16/quickstart-handling-toast-activations-from-win32-apps-in-windows-10/" 
 we have implemented "Activate" API of INotificationActivationCallback  to handle the toast notification.

But as action center include multiple notification. How to uniquely identify the notification. we have to perform different operation on different notification.Activate API "invokedArgs" paramter is always NULL.

Answer (score 2):

Yes,issue is resolved . In order to handle invoke args in action center you need to pass launch argument while creating the toast notification xml.
e.g .

Like in above example we have passed the invoke argument launch with value "invoke arguments" in toast header . Now as "Activate" API is invoked whenever user will click toast notification from action center. you will receive the same parameter in "Activate function invoke args " . Now you can compare the invoke arg value and perform the action . Below is the reference example and link.

```
HRESULT NotificationActivator::Activate(PCWSTR /*appUserModelId*/, PCWSTR invokedArgs,
    const NOTIFICATION_USER_INPUT_DATA* data, ULONG count)
{
    if (invokedArgs == nullptr)
    {
      // Start my app or just do nothing because COM started the app already.
    }
    else if (::wcscmp(invokedArgs, L"replyToComment") == 0)
    {
        ASSERT(count == 1);
        ASSERT(::wcscmp(data[0].Key, L"replyToComment") == 0);

        DoWorkToReply(data[0].Data);
    }

    return S_OK;
}
```

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tiles_and_toasts/2015/10/16/quickstart-handling-toast-activations-from-win32-apps-in-windows-10/